# Docker on Windows: failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"./gradlew\": stat ./gradlew: no such file or directory"

Tags: windows, docker

Here's the Original Command after initial solution search on web. I tried various combinations of using the slash (/) in vain:

```
winpty docker run --privileged --rm -it -v '//c//temp//git//distributions//cache://root//.gradle' --mount type=bind,source=//c//temp//git//distributions,target=//distdestiny_server.in.systems.com/x86/p83-buildenv './gradlew'
C:/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"./gradlew\": stat ./gradlew: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

After further search on web, I used bind-mounts and propogation options with various combinations, but ended up with this error:

```
winpty docker run --privileged --rm -it --mount type=bind,source=//c//temp//git//distributions//cache,target=//root//.gradle --mount type=bind,source=//c//temp//git//distributions,target=/dist,bind-propagation=shared destiny_server.in.systems.com/x86/p83-buildenv './gradlew'
C:/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/docker.exe: Error response from daemon: linux mounts: path /c/temp/git/distributions is mounted on / but it is not a shared mount.
```

Another option I came across is MountFlags. However, the docker documentation only mentions it but doesn't say where to specify it. I couldn't find a way to specify it on the cmd. lines. I find references on the web to some files such as Dockerfile, docer.service, etc. However, I am unable to find any of these files on my system. Is it necessary that I should create swarm to get these files? The only last option I have is to use MountFlags but don't know how and where to specify it.

Docker details: I have just now upgraded docker Client from 17.07.0-ce to 18.03.0-ce on my desktop as I type this content. Still I have the same issue reported.

From Docker Quickstart Terminal:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24302
 Built: Fri Mar 23 08:31:36 2018
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:      18.09.3
  API version:  1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.10.8
  Git commit:   774a1f4
  Built:        Thu Feb 28 06:40:51 2019
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Any help in this regard is much helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using docker on windows is fraught with problems relating to paths. It looks like you're falling down one of these rabbit holes. Assuming .gradle is a directory (it is on my machine):

The way I have solved this is using docker volumes: volumes are different from the drive mapping you're currently using as the files will not appear on the host filesystem, but they are persistent across container executions, which is often sufficient. For example, I have a `/git` directory mounted from a volume in all my dev tools use that to get hold of source code that has been cloned from git. If you need to access these files outside docker, then a volume can be awkward, but if you only used gradle inside a container and never on the host, then you could map your .gradle directory to a volume and simply reuse it across different containers.

Before you do this though, it is a good idea to explicitly create a volume with:

```
 docker volume create gradle
```

There are various techniques that will implicitly create volumes, but personally, I like to be explicit because of the principle of least surprise.

The syntax to mount the volume is similar to the one you used above, but we simply name the volume on the left-hand side of the volume switch:

```
docker container run -it --rm -v gradle:/root/.gradle/ ...
```

There may be another problem in your docker run command though. At the end, you pass the string `'./gradlew'`. You're assuming that this is in the working directory, which could be a problem if the working directory isn't what you think it is. To ensure this doesn't happen, you should state the working directory using the `-w <dir>` switch. Something like:

```
docker container run -it --rm -w /root /v gradle:/root/.gradle/
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I now see the problem. The real issue is  /c/temp/git/distributions on local host is not mounting on /dist folder within container which remains empty. Here's an example: 

` $ pwd 
c/temp/git/distributions 
$ ls 
build.gradle cache/ gradle/ gradle.properties gradlew* 

$ docker run --rm -v /C/temp/git/distributions:/dist destiny_server.in.systems.com/x86/p83-buildenv pwd 
/dist 

$ docker run --rm -v /C/temp/git/distributions:/dist destiny_server.in.systems.com/x86/p83-buildenv ls -l 
total 0 

$ `

I have tried -w & volume as suggested. No difference

Comment: not sure if my previous comment looked like a question. I haven't solved the mount issue yet! Can you or anyone suggest a solution to this **mount** issue (one of those rabbit holes for sure) seen on Windows?

Comment: Check this out, it may help: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly, but, honestly, the volume pattern is the easiest (ish)